# Traffic flow for internal traffic in Juniper SRX 650

Tags: firewall, juniper, acl, srx

I would like to know whether the Juniper SRX by default allows all the source and destination ports if all the devices are from the internal networking range.

For eg, Src-10.10.x.x SrcPrt-any Des-10.20.x.x DesPrt-23 would be allowed by default or we require ACL policies for allowing the traffic in the Juniper SRX series firewalls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Juniper you can actually check the defaults by:

1. Log in as the root user and provide your credentials.
2. In shell mode, navigate to the /etc/config folder. (% cd /etc/config)
3. Use *ls* to list which files are available, there should be something similar to srx650-factory.conf or srx650-defaults.conf
4. Use  *vi filename* to view contents

Steps taken from [SRX650 Services Gateway Hardware Guide](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/release-independent/junos/topics/task/configuration/security-branch-device-configuration-srx650-viewing-factory-default.html), you can also see the sampling of the above steps if in doubt.

**System default security**

Deny all transit traffic.

> By default, the Junos OS denies all traffic through an SRX Series
> device. In fact, an implicit default security policy exists that
> denies all packets. You can change this behavior by configuring a
> standard security policy that permits certain types of traffic, or by
> configuring the default policy to permit all traffic.

**Factory default security policies**

*Trust to trust* permit, *trust to untrust* permit, *untrust to trust* deny

> 1. Trust-to-trust zone policy: Permits all intrazone traffic within the trust zone;
> 2. Trust-to-untrust zone policy: Permits all traffic from the trust zone to the untrust zone; and
> 3. Untrust-to-trust zone policy: Denies all traffic from the untrust zone to the trust zone.

*quotes taken from JNCIS-SEC Study Guide- Part 1, Ch 3:Security Policies